# Laravel Tinker error with SQLite database

Tags: laravel, tinker

Starting from a fresh project:

```
laravel new new-project
cd new-project
touch storage/database/database.sqlite
```

Then at .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=storage/database/database.sqlite
DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
```

The migration succeed...

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan tinker
>>>App\User::all()
```

But when I try to get all users it returns the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/User' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

What I could be missing?

Comment: In which folder/namespace does your User-model reside?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I reinstalled Laravel...

And I didn't realized I was using version Laravel 8
the models are at /app/Models

So the right command would be:

```
>>>App\Models\User::all()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it has something to do with the namespace alias. Try without the **App/**

```
Users::all();
```